# UISlider throwing NSRangeException

Tags: swift

Despite setting each slider's minimum, maximum, and current values to their defaults in the storyboard, moving the slider throws an error saying that the value was somehow moved to 2. In addition, this error only started when I added:

```
var lElbowX = Int()
var rElbowX = Int()
var lElbowY = Int()
var rElbowY = Int()
var lWristX = Int()
var lWristY = Int()
var rWristX = Int()
var rWristY = Int()
var lKneeX = Int()
var lKneeY = Int()
var rKneeX = Int()
var rKneeY = Int()
var lAnkleX = Int()
var lAnkleY = Int()
var rAnkleX = Int()
var rAnkleY = Int()
```

and

```
@IBAction func vertical(_ sender: Any) {//The action function used to be empty
    if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 2) == 1 {//left
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 1 {//lNeck
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 2 {//lShoulder
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 3 {//lElbow
            lElbowY = Int((verticalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 4 {//lWrist
            lWristY = Int((verticalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 5 {//lSpine
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 6 {//lHip
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 7 {//lKnee
            lKneeY = Int((verticalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 8 {//lAnkle
            lAnkleY = Int((verticalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
        }

    }
    if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 2) == 2 {//right
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 1 {//rNeck
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 2 {//rShoulder
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 3 {//rElbow
            rElbowY = Int((verticalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 4 {//rWrist
            rWristY = Int((verticalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 5 {//rSpine
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 6 {//rHip
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 7 {//rKnee
            rKneeY = Int((verticalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 8 {//rAnkle
            rAnkleY = Int((verticalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
        }

    }
}
@IBAction func horizontal(_ sender: Any) {//The action function used to be empty
    if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 2) == 1 {//left
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 1 {//lNeck
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 2 {//lShoulder
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 3 {//lElbow
            lElbowX = Int((horizontalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 4 {//lWrist
            lWristX = Int((horizontalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 5 {//lSpine
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 6 {//lHip
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 7 {//lKnee
            lKneeX = Int((horizontalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 8 {//lAnkle
            lAnkleX = Int((horizontalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
        }

    }
    if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 2) == 2 {//right
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 1 {//rNeck
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 2 {//rShoulder
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 3 {//rElbow
            rElbowX = Int((horizontalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 4 {//rWrist
            rWristX = Int((horizontalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 5 {//rSpine
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 6 {//rHip
            //nothing yet
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 7 {//rKnee
            rKneeX = Int((horizontalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
        }
        if jointPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1) == 8 {//rAnkle
            rAnkleX = Int((horizontalSlider.value - 0.5) * 200)
        }

    }
}
```

Call Stack:

```
2017-07-03 12:38:06.856 Exercise Generator[50942:2970421] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110352d4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d66521e objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001102842eb -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 203
3   UIKit                               0x000000010db187ba -[UIPickerView selectedRowInComponent:] + 76
4   Exercise Generator                  0x000000010d060734 _TFC18Exercise_Generator12selectorView8verticalfP_T_ + 180
5   Exercise Generator                  0x000000010d062713 _TToFC18Exercise_Generator12selectorView8verticalfP_T_ + 67
6   UIKit                               0x000000010db368bc -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
7   UIKit                               0x000000010dcbcc38 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
8   UIKit                               0x000000010dcbcf51 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
9   UIKit                               0x000000010dda60d4 -[UISlider beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:] + 1132
10  UIKit                               0x000000010dcbb893 -[UIControl touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 179
11  UIKit                               0x000000010dba4285 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2043
12  UIKit                               0x000000010dba5c33 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
13  UIKit                               0x000000010db529ab -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
14  UIKit                               0x000000010e33f72d __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
15  UIKit                               0x000000010e338463 __handleEventQueue + 4879
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001102f7761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001102dc98c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001102dbe76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001102db884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
20  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011228ca6f GSEventRunModal + 161
21  UIKit                               0x000000010db34c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
22  Exercise Generator                  0x000000010d0674ef main + 111
23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011130268d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the first few frames of the stack trace. I'll cut out the image and address columns to avoid scrolling:

```
'*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   objc_exception_throw + 48
2   -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 203
3   -[UIPickerView selectedRowInComponent:] + 76
4   _TFC18Exercise_Generator12selectorView8verticalfP_T_ + 180
```

We see that your `vertical(_:)` method asks the picker view for the selected row in a component, and the picker view tries to get an object from an array. The array throws the exception, because it was given index 2, but its valid indexes are only 0 and 1.

The picker view probably has an array of components, and is trying to get component 2 from the array, because (in two different places in `vertical(_:)`) you ask it about component 2.

My guess is your picker view only has two components, with indexes 0 and 1.

Comment: Whoops! I completely forgot that the components are numbered starting with 0.